# How to store literals using @entity.values on Slot IBM Conversation Service?

Tags: arrays, watson, watson-conversation, slot

I'm trying use slots on my dialog nodes on Watson conversation but seems that is not properly useful if you want to play with array of literal. I've an entity "@email" that is a pattern so I must use `.literal` if I want to store the "real value", that is sent by the user, on a context variable. Trouble starts when I try to use `@entity.values` to store all values that are sent by the user. Actually is not possible to store an array of literals and I'm stuck at this point.

Anyone developed a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `literal` is a method, not an attribute. The `entities` contains a `location` field, which you can programatically use at the application layer to parse the input text.

If you want to pull them out in conversation, you can use a counter to walk through the entities.

For example:

In your slot node "Then respond with" add the following context bit.

```
  "context": {
    "counter": "<? entities.size() ?>",
    "literals": ""
  },
```

Next create three child nodes.

**Node 1**:  Create a dummy node, set condition to true. Have it jump to the second node.

**Node 2**: For the second node, set the condition to `$counter > 0` and add the following code to the JSON section.

```
  "context": {
    "counter": "<? $counter - 1 ?>",
    "literals": "<? entities[$counter].literal + ',' + $literals ?>"
  },
```

Have it jump back to Node 1. The reason for this is Conversation will not allow you to jump to the same node.

**Node 3**: Have it output the answer. For example: `Literal Values: $literals`

Here is a sample workspace.

https://pastebin.com/xwgnLq9n

### Warning

Watson Conversation has a built in endless loop detection. If a node is hit 50 times in one request, it will throw the following error:

```
Detected recursion when processing the node with id
[node_20_1513835954092]. This node has been already processed [50] times
in this execution step
```

At which point the node will fail and you will get no result back. So if you expect more than 50 entities then you need to do this at the application layer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @davidesarais no worries. Don't forget to mark the question answered if this resolves your question.

Comment: answer allow me to create something near to desiderata.Next issue to solve is:
I have a node with 2 slots that can store X and Y (entities)
Your solution fully works for the Y becouse user can specify an array of Y. Problem starts when the user type the first input as "blabla Y Y Y" so Watson must fill also the second slot X and ask the user for X. Then the user type a X and finally the flow can continue with dummy node for extract literals from Y - but - entity Y at this time is not more valid!

Solution is force the user for text first X and then Y or X and Y at the same time.